# Gráfico não aparece na tela do celular

Tags: android, plot

No desenvolvimento de um aplicativo, estou plotando um gráfico como resultado final das entradas de dados do usuário.

A questão principal é que, como vou apresentar no código a seguir, eu tenho um FOR que vai plotando cada ponto com base nos cálculos já programados. Se eu coloco o XYPLOT do programa dentro do FOR, o gráfico sai corretamente, porém a legenda apresenta 100 vezes cada ponto plotado. (O FOR está dividido em 100 pontos e cada ponto tem que ser plotado no gráfico). Agora, se eu coloco o código de plotagem fora do FOR, a legenda sai corretamente, porém o gráfico não é plotado.

Alguém pode ajudar?! Obrigada!

**Código de plotagem dentro do FOR**

```html
deformacao_aco_compressao_variavel_dominio1 = 0.01;

        for (i=0; i<100; i++){

            Normal_dominio1 = this.Normal_Aco_Compressao_Dominio1() + this.Normal_Aco_Tracao_Dominio1();

            Normal_vetor_dominio1[i] = Normal_dominio1;

            Momento_dominio1 = this.Momento_Aco_Compressao_Dominio1() + this.Momento_Aco_Tracao_Dominio1();

            Momento_vetor_dominio1[i] = Momento_dominio1;

            // Código para plotar o gráfico
            XYSeries dominio1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(this.Normal_vetor_dominio1[i]), Arrays.asList(this.Momento_vetor_dominio1[i]),  "D.1");
            LineAndPointFormatter dominio1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, null);
            graph.addSeries(dominio1, dominio1Format);

            deformacao_aco_compressao_variavel_dominio1 = deformacao_aco_compressao_variavel_dominio1 - (0.01 - this.Deformacao_Aco_Compressao_Dominio1()) / 100;

        }
```

**Como fica com o código de plotagem dentro do FOR**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como fica com o código de plotagem fora do FOR**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]